# WebBrowser Control does not display loaded page in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an Authorization form used for getting the user to authorize my app in an to use their name on their behalf, and this works well in windows 7, but seems to fail in Windows 10. I have attempted to add Registry Keys as suggested in some other questions, and also adding a 'WebBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;' in case that was needed. In any instance, it appears that the control is functional, in that it navigates to the page and says the document is loaded, but nothing displays on the screen.

```
    static Authorize form = new Authorize();
    static void Main2(object state)
    {
        Application.Run((Form)state);
    }
    static Authorize form = new Authorize();
    public static Authorize Create()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Main2);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start(form);
        form.FormClosing += Authorize_FormClosing;
        return form;
    }
    public void InitForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormClosing += Authorize_FormClosing;
    }
    public Authorize(string Url)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AuthCont.AllowNavigation = true;
        AuthCont.Navigate(Url);
    }
    public void NavigateTo(string Url)
    {
        AuthCont.Navigate(Url);
    }
```

Comment: The WebBrowser control uses IE. Is IE installed? Modifying the registry isn't going to help if the binary isn't there

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos IE is installed and works for the same web page as the URI that is being sent programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the browser version with the windows and add proper reg key for your app

```
        int BrowserVer, RegVal;

        // get the installed IE version
        using (WebBrowser Wb = new WebBrowser())
            BrowserVer = Wb.Version.Major;

        // set the appropriate IE version
        if (BrowserVer >= 11)
            RegVal = 11001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 10)
            RegVal = 10001;
        else if (BrowserVer == 9)
            RegVal = 9999;
        else if (BrowserVer == 8)
            RegVal = 8888;
        else
            RegVal = 7000;

        // set the actual key
        Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", "[your_exe_name, ex: myapp.exe]", RegVal);
```

Comment: I did state in my question I had already attempted to change the registry keys to no avail. Thank you for the response though.